# Update customer address attribute via upgrade script Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.3

I want to update validate_rules column value for specific billing address field like telephone.
so can anyone suggest me how to do this.

Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 0):

Happy Coding !!

```
    namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

    use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
    use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeRepository;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Config as EavConfig;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

    class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
    {

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var EavConfig
     */
    protected $eavConfig;

    /**
     * @var AttributeRepository
     */
    protected $attributeRepository;

    /**
     * UpgradeData constructor.
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param EavConfig $eavConfig
     * @param AttributeRepository $attributeRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        EavConfig $eavConfig,
        AttributeRepository $attributeRepository
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', 'updateAttribute(
                Customer::ENTITY,
                '34', 
                [
                    'is_required' => 0,
                ]
            );
            }
        }
    }
```

Just change 34 to your ID, ID you can find in `eav_attribute` table

```
 bin/magento setup:upgrade
```